# What will happen if Parliament votes "no" on each of the Brexit-related votes to be held on the 12th, 13th and 14th of March?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, parliament

It [is being reported](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-47373996) that there will be a series of votes on the 12th, 13th and 14th of March:

> The prime minister said she will put her withdrawal agreement - including any changes she has agreed with the EU - to a meaningful vote by 12 March.
>
> If that fails, MPs will be offered two separate votes:
>
> One, on the following day, on whether MPs support a no-deal Brexit - so the UK would "only leave without a deal on 29 March if there is explicit consent in the House for that outcome"
>
> If that fails, then MPs will get a vote by 14 March on requesting an extension to the two-year Article 50 negotiation process to delay EU withdrawal beyond 29 March

But what happens if Parliament votes against each of these? That is, what happens if Parliament votes against Theresa May's deal on the 12th, votes that it does not support a No Deal Brexit on the 13th, and then votes against extending the date of departure on the 14th? Firstly, what is the "will of Parliament" deemed to be in this case, and secondly, what are the practical consequences? The default, of course, is that the UK leaves on the 29th of March without a deal; yet Parliament will have said (in its vote on the 13th) that it does not support this eventuality.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90304/discussion-on-question-by-hammerite-what-will-happen-if-parliament-votes-no-on).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like the BBC have stepped up to answer this very question.
[Full Article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-47373996) on the three vote offers.

Per the flow chart below, if MPs vote no at all three votes, the UK will leave the EU without a deal.

However, at the moment it is my understanding that this information is speculative in that the text of the votes and any possible amendments have not yet been released and the details may change this flow diagram.

[image: Three Votes Diagram]

Comment: As discussed in the comments on the Question, it may be this flow is wrong, particularly because it makes vote 2 and 3 mutually contradictory. So if vote 2 is flipped to "pass" an "No no-deal", then failing to pass the extension bill could result in revocation of Article 50.

Comment: If this is what the BBC (a presumably knowledgeable source) is currently saying based on their current information, then this is a valid answer, even if the details change later.

Comment: If this is accurate, I didn't realize the Marcth 13th vote was a simple absolute positive/negative. Ofcourse this doesn't cover the political ramifications.

Comment: This flow chart implies that 50 percent of the routes result in a no-deal exit, or 2/3rds of them when you discount the _unlikely_ 4th option (MPs approving the PM's deal, when they have already decisively rejected it). But many MPs make this choice whilst still having a nervous eye on their Constituency, most of which voted _Leave_ in the Referendum.

Comment: @Ed999 Your 4th option is the first option on the chart.

Comment: @ouflak as I mentioned in the answer I don't think anyone knows the details of exactly what each vote will be yet, which is why the diagram and potential outcomes is still speculative. But given the flow chart exactly matched the question it seemed worth posting as an answer.

Comment: A "revocation of Article 50" would need the repeal of the Withdrawal Act and mean staying in the EU; that would overturn the Referendum result. Voting on a Repeal Act would surely not be possible before 29 March. It would therefore require an extension from the EU [which would have been defeated already in Vote 3], it could still fail, and would probably be seen as a gross betrayal by the winning side in the Referendum.

Comment: remember that Brussels has already stated there will be no extension granted. Of course this was done to pressure the UK to reject the leave vote completely and beg to be allowed to remain in the EU, and they may well do different if begged to at the last moment, if May promises to stay in the EU anyway but just needs a bit more time for example.

Comment: Revokation of Article 50 is something the UK can unilaterally do, as stated by the European Court of Justice. Getting an extension from the EU for further negotiations is uncertain.

Comment: The "PM will need to request an extension from the EU" should also have a "FAIL" option leading to "UK leaves EU without a deal" (this is not an inconceivable scenario).

Comment: Is it appropriate to update the answer to this question in the light of history?  It might be useful to users of the sight in the future looking for a historical perspective.

Comment: Here's an [updated](http://i66.tinypic.com/2ushjbm.jpg) version.